# Save image data to a database

Tags: database, vb.net, image

I need to make an app into which we can load pics or a folder containing pics. The pics should load into a kind of list which shows the pic according to the selected item. I should be able to rate the image from 1 to  10 and add a description to it.

Finally the app should be able to save both these data to file or database which loads the rating and description on next startup.

Comment: and your question is...

Comment: I just coded the part which loads the images from a selected folder into a FlowLayoutPanel. Now how do I save the description from the textbox and the rating from the combobox into a database with reference to the pic so that it loads this data on the next launch.

Comment: Is there a way to embed this data directly into the image file? MP3 files have a lot of details in them, do images have some too? Another option could be to get the filename of each image and save the data (description and rating) in a text file according to the name and then retrieve it. What do you suggest and how to do it?

Comment: There is Exif data... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format. This is mainly used by cameras to store technical data about camera settings when photo is taken. I created web app that allowed users to upload photo and then add comment. I achieved this by using an ajax upload control (with clientside routine that reduced size and resolution of photo to keep bandwidth down also to standardise the photo size). The photo uploaded to central location and path was saved into a db. DB record also had fields for comments etc which were populated from a form that the user filled in.

Comment: @Mych I'm using VB.Net. Can you help me with that?

Comment: 4 hours and still no response? I need this as soon as possible. Anyone knows how to set and get the rating and description of an image?